# how to store data from editable gridview before writing to db

Tags: c#, gridview

I've got a gridview that I populate from the database, I want to allow the user to edit and add to the gridview. Once they've completed the changes/additions then submit it to the database. Can someone help me how to do this?

This is my code so far

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowEditing="Grds_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="Grd_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="Grd_RowUpdating" Width="500px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="NameID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ID")%>' />
                <asp:Label ID="LblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView><asp:Button ID="btnok" Text="OK" Height="25" Width="25" runat="server" />
```

and code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindGrid(int.Parse(hfID.Value));
      }

        protected void BindGrid(int iPerson)
        {
            DataContext dc = new DataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);

            var qry = from p in dc.GetDetails(iPerson)
                      select p;

            Grd.DataSource = qry;
            Grd.DataBind();
        }
   protected void Grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            Grd.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            BindGrid(int.Parse(hfID.Value));

        }
        protected void Grd_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            Grd.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrid(int.Parse(hfID.Value));
        }

        protected void Grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

        }


 protected void btOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//update the database with changes
        }
```

Comment: you want to save on button click rt ? or on each row editing

Comment: Yes, the button isn't in the gridview. I've just updated the code with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your button click,*dtCurrentTable* is your gridview binding datatable.

```
int rowIndex = 0;
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection(); 

for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Count; i++)
{
//extract the TextBox values
Label box1 = (Label)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblbedroom");
DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddpAccomodates");
DropDownList box3 = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddpBathroom");
DropDownList box4 = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddpBedType");
TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtPrices");
DropDownList box6 = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddpMiniStay");
//get the values from the TextBoxes
//then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
sc.Add("Private Room" + box1.Text + "," + box2.SelectedItem.Value + "," + box3.SelectedItem.Value + "," + box4.SelectedItem.Value + "," + box5.Text + "," + box6.SelectedItem.Value);
rowIndex++;
}

InsertToDb(sc);
```

Then

```
private void InsertToDb(StringCollection sc)
    {
        string[] splitItems = null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
         //split and save in to db here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I need.  The grid is initially populated from a stored procedure.  The user should be able to update the grid but not update the database until all edits have been made.  Also they should be able to add a new row, again without updating the database until the OK button is clicked.  So essentially all edits should be stored in viewstate or similar then read from the view state to refresh the grid when edits are made, then update the database with edits and additions on click of OK button.